# How to get colour palette of chart in excel add-in using office JS?

Tags: reactjs, office-js, excel-addins, office-js-helpers

We are developing an excel add-in with react and office js APIs. We have added a chart and set the color to the chart from the color palette(**chart-design -> Change Colours -> Colourful palette4**).

**Please refer the below screenshot ->**

[image]

We wanted to get the color palette name or colors set to the chart. We checked through the office js documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.chart?view=excel-js-preview, We can get Style for the chart but we are not able to find anything related to getting a color palette.

Can anyone please help us to understand how to get a color palette using office js APIs?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `colorScheme` API under `ChartAreaFormat`, here is a sample code to get the color scheme

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const chart = sheet.charts.getItemAt(0);
    chart.load("format/colorScheme");
    await context.sync();
    console.log(chart.format.colorScheme);

  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped me.